# On fragment delay method not working?

Tags: android

I used delay method on fragment in onCreateView method, but its working only one time, when second time i goto again fragment this delay method is not calling

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {    
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout, container, false);

    autoMatedClicker();
    return rootView;
}

private void autoMatedClicker() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            citySelectionList();
        }
    }, 50);
}
```

Comment: i think this is because you call the `autoMatedClicker()` and afaik it is not necessarily called multiple times when reusing the fragment. you should check the fragment lifecycle to find a better place to call your method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `autoMatedClicker()` function of the fragment in the `onResume()` function of the fragment. Also note that the fragments `onResume()` will be called only when the parent activity's `onResume()` is called.